# Pyspark optimization with loops

Tags: python, optimization, pyspark

I have a table with the columns items, date, and sales. I have the total sales by date and item. I need to find the combination of 3 items which minimizes the standard deviation. The table looks like this: e.g.

```
# df:
# +------------+----------+------------+
# |item        |      date|sales       |
# +------------+----------+------------+
# |         325|2021-05-01|     8524.64|
# |         400|2021-05-01|     9939.59|
# |         314|2021-05-03|      5466.3|
# |         267|2021-05-04|     6471.63|
# |         387|2021-05-04|     5406.85|
# +------------+----------+------------+
```

I need to find the group of items, that when grouped together the standard deviation is at its minimum. In order to do this I made a loop but it takes too long, this is how I thought about it:

```
bestis=[]
besti=0
best_score=99999
t=1
list_items= [325,400,314,267,387] #all values of item column
while t<=3:
    if besti in all_other_stores: all_other_stores.remove(besti)

for i in list_items:
    df_filtered = df.filter(col("item").isin(bestis+[i])
    stddev_sales = df_filtered.select(stddev("sales")).collect()[0][0]
    
    if stddev_sales< best_stdev:
       best_stdev = stddev_sales
       besti=i 

bestis= bestis+[besti]
    t += 1
```

At the end of the first loop, I will have the item with the min standard deviation. e.g: [325] At the end of the second loop, I should have the best two items that minimize the standard deviation. e.g. [325,400], at the end of third loop I should have [325,400,387] assuming that 387 is the additional item that minimizes the standard deviation. I got a working code, the only problem is that it takes too long because of the loop

How could I use a pySpark map function instead in this case? Or maybe is there some kind of optimization algorithm that will do this faster? like given the list, find me the best combo of 3 items that minimizes the standard deviation?

Comment: is the end objective to get the list of items `bestis` that has the least stddev?

Comment: are the items in `list_items` kept based on some priority? can `list_items` be `list_items= [325,400,387,267,314]`, instead of the current?

Comment: The list_items are just the distinct items of the column "items", so their order doesn't matter.

Comment: @samkart, yes, the end objective would be to minimize the standard deviation for a combination of 3 items within the list of items

Comment: i'm guessing those 3 items can be any permutation from the `list_items`. so, you'll need to check for all permutations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253879/discussion-between-marcela-bejarano-and-samkart).